# Matplotlib: ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (27), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (24)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

heating_activity = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0.06, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


# Set figure size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))

# Plotting
plt.bar(np.arange(0, len(heating_activity)), heating_activity, color='blue', width=0.75)
plt.xlabel('Time of the day', size=17)
plt.ylabel('Heat Pump Modulation', size=17)
plt.title('Heating Activity Over Time for the DHW Tank', size=20)

# Setting x-axis ticks
ticks = np.arange(0, len(heating_activity), 4)  # Adjusted to include only the start of each hour
labels = ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00']

# Setting y-axis ticks
plt.yticks([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], ['0', '0.25', '0.5', '0.75', '1'], size=17)

plt.xticks(ticks, labels, rotation=90, size=17)
plt.yticks()


plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/heating_plot_modulating.jpg", dpi=200)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

And I get the error "ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (27), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (24)." I have 96 values for the heating activity (for each 15 minutes of a day) and I want to plot the x-label-ticks for every hour from 00:00 to 23:00.

Comment: "I have 96 values for the heating activity (for each 15 minutes of a day)", but `activity_heating` list has 106 items... So `ticks = np.arange(0, len(heating_activity), 4)` generates an array of 27 items (ceil(106 / 4))